# MPSImageIntegral returning all zeros

Tags: macos, metal, metal-performance-shaders

I am trying to use `MPSImageIntegral` to calculate the sum of some elements in an `MTLTexture`. This is what I'm doing:

```c
std::vector<float> integralSumData;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    integralSumData.push_back((float)i);

MTLTextureDescriptor *textureDescriptor = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:MTLPixelFormatR32Float
                                                                                             width:(integralSumData.size()) height:1 mipmapped:NO];
textureDescriptor.usage = MTLTextureUsageShaderRead | MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite;
id<MTLTexture> texture = [_device newTextureWithDescriptor:textureDescriptor];

// Calculate the number of bytes per row in the image.
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = integralSumData.size() * sizeof(float);

MTLRegion region =
{
    { 0, 0, 0 },                   // MTLOrigin
    {integralSumData.size(), 1, 1} // MTLSize
};

// Copy the bytes from the data object into the texture
[texture replaceRegion:region
           mipmapLevel:0
             withBytes:integralSumData.data()
           bytesPerRow:bytesPerRow];


MTLTextureDescriptor *textureDescriptor2 = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:MTLPixelFormatR32Float
                                                                                              width:(integralSumData.size()) height:1 mipmapped:NO];
textureDescriptor2.usage = MTLTextureUsageShaderRead | MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite;
id<MTLTexture> outtexture = [_device newTextureWithDescriptor:textureDescriptor2];


// Create a MPS filter.
MPSImageIntegral *integral = [[MPSImageIntegral alloc] initWithDevice: _device];
MPSOffset offset = { 0,0,0};
[integral setOffset:offset];
[integral setEdgeMode:MPSImageEdgeModeZero];
[integral encodeToCommandBuffer:commandBuffer sourceTexture:texture destinationTexture:outtexture];

[commandBuffer commit];
[commandBuffer waitUntilCompleted];
```

But, when I check my `outtexture` values, its all zeroes. Am I doing something wrong? Is this a correct way in which I shall use `MPSImageIntegral`?

I'm using the following code to read values written into the `outTexture`:

```cpp
float outData[100];
[outtexture getBytes:outData bytesPerRow:bytesPerRow fromRegion:region mipmapLevel:0];
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    std::cout << outData[i] << "\n";
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you commit the command buffer (don't see that in your code)? Note that, since you're on macOS, you will also need to synchronize your output texture so that it can be read by the CPU.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Yes, I did commit the command buffer. I forgot to add that to the sample code I posted on SO. I have added those lines to the question now. As for the synchronisation I have added `waitUntilCompleted`, shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: You'll also need to use MPSImage's `synchronizeOnCommandBuffer`.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Call `synchronizeOnCommandBuffer` on what? I don't create an MPSImage anywhere. Can this be called on `MPSImageIntegral`?

Comment: Oh my bad, I saw MPS in there and assumed you used MPSImage objects. If you're using MTLTextures, you'll need to do the synchronization using a `MTLBlitCommandEncoder`. This copies the texture from the GPU back to the CPU.

Comment: Adding a `synchronizeResource` from `MTLBlitCommandEncoder` did the trick. Thanks! Can you post this as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: As a continued question: If I have to pass the outTexture of MPSImageIntegral to another compute kernel, I wouldn't need the BlitEncoder then, right?

Comment: That is correct. The blitting is only needed to copy the texture from the GPU to the CPU. This actually depends on the storage mode of the texture (it's not _always_ necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Matthijis: All I had to do was use an `MTLBlitEncoder` to make sure I synchronise my `MTLTexture` before reading it into CPU, and it worked like charm!

Comment: Can you add the line of code needed to solve this problem and where it would be placed?

Comment: @Demitri I do not have the exact code that I used at that time. But just before I copied content to CPU using `getBytes`, I created a `MTLBlitCommandEncoder` and called `[blitCE synchronizeTexture:myTexture slice:syncSlice level:0];` and then ending the encoder of course.