# Running MPSImageIntegral for UInt32_t

Tags: macos, metal, metal-performance-shaders

So, I have been trying to run some MPS Kernels. Based on my previous question here: [MPSImageIntegral returning all zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56429189/mpsimageintegral-returning-all-zeros)
where I was trying to run MPSImageIntegral on float values. Now, I moved on to `uint32_t` values. But turns, out I always get an assert

> /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/MetalPerformanceShaders/MetalPerformanceShaders-121.4.2/MPSImage/Filters/MPSIntegral.mm:196:
>   failed assertion `Destination 0x600003b62760 texture format does not
>   match source 0x600003b62680 texture format'

The assert is misleading, since my texture types are not a mismatch.

This is what I do to create my `MTLTexture`

```
+ (id<MTLTexture>) createTestTexture: (float)val metalDevice:(id<MTLDevice>)device textureWidth:(int)widthTex
{
    std::vector<uint32_t> testData;
    for(int i = 0; i < widthTex; i++)
        testData.push_back(i);

    MTLTextureDescriptor* desc = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:MTLPixelFormatR32Uint 
                    width: widthTex height:1 mipmapped:NO];
    [desc setResourceOptions:MTLResourceStorageModeManaged];
    [desc setStorageMode:MTLStorageModeManaged];
    [desc setUsage:(MTLTextureUsageShaderRead | MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite)];

    id<MTLTexture> tex = [device newTextureWithDescriptor:desc];

    MTLRegion texDataRegion = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, widthTex, 1);
    [tex replaceRegion:texDataRegion mipmapLevel:0 withBytes:testData.data() bytesPerRow:1024];
    return tex;
}
```

This is the function that I use to create both my input and output texture.
Then I go on to run my MPSImageIntegral like this:

```
id<MTLTexture> inTex = [ViewController createTestTexture:1.0f metalDevice:_device textureWidth:100];
id<MTLTexture> outTex = [ViewController createTestTexture:1.0f metalDevice:_device textureWidth:100];

id<MTLCommandQueue> _commandQueue = [_device newCommandQueue];
id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [_commandQueue commandBuffer];

// Create a MPS filter.
[integral encodeToCommandBuffer:commandBuffer sourceTexture:inTex destinationTexture:outTex];
```

Based, on the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/image_filters?language=objc
`MPSImageIntegral` supports `MTLPixelFormatR32Uint`, Is there something wrong that I'm doing here?

Comment: Where does the `bytesPerRow:1024` come from?

Comment: The documentation says that `bytesPerRow` needs to be a multiple of `256`, so I just added that randomly since, my data on which I was testing is always less than `1024` bytes.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Do you think that will create a problem?