# MPSImageIntegral returns all zeroes when images are smaller

Tags: ios, metal, metal-performance-shaders

I have a Metal shader that processes an iPad Pro video frame to generate a (non-displayed) RGBA32Float image in a color attachment.  That texture is then put through an MPSImageIntegral filter, encoded into the same command buffer as the shader, which results in an output image of the same size and format.  In the command buffer’s completion handler, I read out the last pixel in the filtered image (containing the sum of all pixels in the input image) using this code:

```
let src = malloc(16)    // 4 Floats per pixel * 4 bytes/Float
let region = MTLRegionMake2D(imageWidth - 1, imageHeight - 1, 1, 1) // last pixel in image
outputImage!.getBytes(src!, bytesPerRow: imageWidth * 16, from: region, mipmapLevel: 0)
let sum = src!.bindMemory(to: Float.self, capacity: 4)
NSLog("sum = \(sum[0]), \(sum[1]), \(sum[2]), \(sum[3])")
```

That works correctly as long as the textures holding the input and filtered images are both the same size as the IPad’s display, 2048 x 2732, though it's slow with such large images.

To speed it up, I had the shader generate just a ¼ size (512 x 683) RGBA32Float image instead, and use that same size and format for the filter’s output.  But in that case, the sum that I read out is always just zeroes.

By capturing GPU frames in the debugger, I can see that the dependency graphs look the same in both cases (except for the reduced texture sizes in the latter case), and that the shader and filter work as expected in both cases, based on the appearance of the input and filtered textures as shown in the debugger.  **So why is it I can no longer successfully read out that filtered data, when the only change was to reduce the size of the filter's input and output images?**

Some things I’ve already tried, to no avail:

1. Using 512 x 512 (and other size) images, to avoid possible padding artifacts in the 512 x 683 images.
2. Looking at other pixels, near the middle of the output image, which also contain non-zero data according to the GPU snapshots, but which read as 0 when using the smaller images.
3. Using a MTLBlitCommandEncoder in the same command buffer to copy the output pixel to a MTLBuffer, instead of, or in addition to, using getBytes.  (That was suggested by the answer to [this MacOS question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56429189/2832475), which is not directly applicable to iOS.)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if I change the render pass descriptor's storeAction for the shader's color attachment that receives the initial RGBA32Float input image from .dontCare to .store, then the code works for 512 x 683 images as well as 2048 x 2732 ones.

Why it worked without that for the larger images I still don't know.

I also don't know why this store action matters, as the filtered output image was already being successfully generated, even when its input was not stored.